# Are bound services always foreground?

Tags: android, foreground-service

I need to start a `foreground service` for my app so that it keeps running and is unlikely to be killed even if the app is in the background. The is a method for this, `startForeground`.

I also need to communicate with the service, so I gather the easiest option would be to bind to it (I am planning for it to run in the same process to be able to just cast the returned IBinder to my class and just call methods on it). However, nowhere can I find information about bound `foreground services`.

Reading through the docs and tutorials I found information that one of the flags to`bindService` is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND to prevent the service from getting foreground priority.

Does this mean that by default every `bound service` is also a `foreground` one, and it needs notifications and the like (the docs never actually mention it so I guess not)?

If my app uses a foreground service, can the app be killed while in the background?

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's talk about services. Service can be **started**, **bound** and **both of them**. So you actually can make *startService()* and make *startForeground()* after it, but when you're going to *bindService()*, you can remove notification and make service not foreground (seems like flag BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND for this situation). Bound service is not foreground by itself (they have priority of component that are bounding to service). As i know to make foreground bound service, you can't just call *startForeground()* (it will not work, no notification will be added in status bar), so the only way is to make *startService()* and in *onStartCommand()* handle action that will do only *startForeground()*.

So by default bound service isn't foreground, you don't need notification. Your app can be killed in any time by the system or by user in app's settings (Force stop), but if you want to let system know that your service is really important for user and app, you make it foreground so system will not touch it until system has enough memory for your process.